# How do i check for duplicate values present in a Dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to map a function that takes a dictionary as the input and returns a list of the keys.
The keys in the list must be of only the unique values present in the dictionary.

So, this is what I have done.

```
bDict={}
for key,value in aDict.items():
    if bDict.has_key(value) == False:
        bDict[value]=key
    else:
        bDict.pop(value,None)
```

This is the output :

```
>>> aDict.keys()
Out[4]: [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10]

>>> aDict.values()
Out[5]: [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0]

>>> bDict.keys()
Out[6]: [0, 1, 2, 4]

>>> bDict.values()
Out[7]: [10, 1, 3, 8]
```

But, the expected output should be for `bDict.values()` : `[*1,3,8*]`

Comment: One idea is to traverse the dictionary on the keys, and insert the values as keys into another dictionary. If the new key exists, you've got a double value in your original dictionary.

Comment: Do an ordinary traversal of the original dictionary, and you'll have both the key and the values. If you don't know how to do that, please find a tutorial on dictionaries

Comment: So, this is what i have done. 

values=aDict.values()
keys=aDict.keys()
bDict={}
for key,value in aDict.items():
    if bDict.has_key(value) == False:
        bDict[value]=key
    else:
        bDict.pop(value,None)

This is the output : 
aDict.keys()
Out[4]: [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10]

aDict.values()
Out[5]: [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0]

bDict.keys()
Out[6]: [0, 1, 2, 4]

bDict.values()
Out[7]: [10, 1, 3, 8]

but the expected output should be for bDict.Values : [1,3,8]

edited my original post since this is all cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

**CODE**

```
aDict = { 1:1, 3:2, 6:0, 7:0, 8:4, 10:0, 11:0}
bDict = {}

for i,j in aDict.items():
    if j not in bDict:
        bDict[j] = [i]

    else:
        bDict[j].append(i)

print map(lambda x: x[0],filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1,bDict.values()))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 3, 8]
```

Comment: It works with the current `aDict`, but fails with a set like `aDict = { 1:1, 3:2, 6:0, 7:0, 8:4, 10:0, 11:2 }`. Note that the value 2 is set only two times, not three (as for the value 0). It fails due to the removal within your current `elif` block.

Comment: Now it looks more like it. But what I don't really like about neither mine nor your solution is non-intuitive variable names...

Comment: Sorry to say, but do you think adding the lambda function made it more readable?!  :-) The removed `blocked` variable was maybe the most intuitive variable name of all. 
What about `i` and `j`? In addition it now fails again when adding `11:2` to `aDict`. Please do test your code with some input variants before posting

Comment: It is not failing with `11:2` giving me `[1,8]` as output.

Comment: My bad, when testing I changed the `aDict` wrongly. But the change into a dictionary with arrays, is complicating the code and hinders readability, although a somewhat neat idea.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears you're creating a new dictionary with the keys and values inverted, keeping pairs where the value is unique.  You can figure out which of the items are unique first then build a dictionary off of that.

```
def distinct_values(d):
    from collections import Counter
    counts = Counter(d.itervalues())
    return { v: k for k, v in d.iteritems() if counts[v] == 1 }
```

This yields the following result:

```
>>> distinct_values({ 1:1, 3:2, 6:0, 7:0, 8:4, 10:0 })
{1: 1, 2: 3, 4: 8}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a new dictionary, just to get the list of keys where the values are unique, as far as I understood the question that is.

Comment: If only the key list is to be returned, it seems one can use: `return [ k for k,v in d.iteritems() if counts[v] == 1 ]`

Comment: HeHe... I understand the confusion, look at the original question without the edits which came after a comment regarding a possible solution made by myself!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (with two versions of the `aDict` to test a rand case which failed in another solution):

```
#aDict = { 1:1, 3:2, 6:0, 7:0, 8:4, 10:0}
aDict = { 1:1, 3:2, 6:0, 7:0, 8:4, 10:0, 11:2}
seenValues = {}
uniqueKeys = set()

for aKey, aValue in aDict.items():

    if aValue not in seenValues:
        # Store the key of the value, and assume it is unique
        seenValues[aValue] = aKey
        uniqueKeys.add(aKey)

    elif seenValues[aValue] in uniqueKeys:
        # The value has been seen before, and the assumption of
        # it being unique was wrong, so remove it 
        uniqueKeys.remove(seenValues[aValue])
        print "Remove non-unique key/value pair: {%d, %d}" % (aKey, aValue) 

    else:
        print "Non-unique key/value pair: {%d, %d}" % (aKey, aValue) 
print "Unique keys: ", sorted(uniqueKeys)
```

And this produces the output:

> Remove non-unique key/value pair: {7, 0}
>   Non-unique key/value pair: {10, 0}
>   Remove non-unique key/value pair: {11, 2}
>   Unique keys:  [1, 8]

Or with original version of `aDict`:

> Remove non-unique key/value pair: {7, 0}
>   Non-unique key/value pair: {10, 0}
>   Unique keys:  [1, 3, 8]

Answer (score 0):

As a python 2.7 one-liner,

```
[k for k,v in aDict.iteritems() if aDict.values().count(v) == 1]
```

Note that the above

- Calls `aDict.values()` many times, once for each entry in the dictionary, and
- Calls `aDict.values().count(v)` multiple times for each replicated value.

This is not a problem if the dictionary is small. If the dictionary isn't small, the creation and destruction of those duplicative lists and the duplicative calls to `count()` may be costly. It may help to cache the value of `adict.values()`, and it may also help to create a dictionary that maps the values in the dictionary to the number of occurrences as a dictionary entry value.